# Local Storage font family

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I need some help with local storage. So far I have some js which allows the user to change the font family of a div, and it manages to save the users selection locally. However, I can't figure out how to apply the font family value (i.e helvetica) to the div on reload.

```
    function updateh1family() {
var selector = document.getElementById('selecth1FontFamily');
var family = selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].value;
var h1 = document.getElementById('edit')
h1.style.fontFamily = family;    

var font = document.getElementById('edit');
font.onchange = function() {
document.getElementById('edit').style.fontFamily = family;
localStorage.setItem('font', family);
}
font.value = localStorage.getItem('font');
font.onchange();

if (localStorage.length != 0) {
document.getElementById('edit').style.fontFamily = localStorage.font;
document.getElementById('edit').value = localStorage.font;
 }}
```

Comment: You have to separate the code which react on change in dropdown list and which react on load event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this solution:http://jsfiddle.net/jy424/2/

```
var selector = document.getElementById('selecth1FontFamily'),
    text= document.getElementById('edit');

if (localStorage.length != 0) {
  text.style.fontFamily = localStorage.font;
  text.value = localStorage.font;
}else{
  localStorage.setItem('font', '');
}

selector.onchange = function(){
  var family = this.value;
  text.style.fontFamily = family;
  localStorage.font = family;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's simple

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload
    {
        if(localStorage.font)
        {
             document.getElementById('FontDiv').style.fontFamily = localStorage.font;
        }
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use `classes` instead of trying to manipulate the styles directly. jQuery makes this very easy, assuming you are using the library. You tags say you are, but your code suggests not.

```
.on { font-family: arial; }

$(function () {
  localStorage.setItem('class', 'on');
  $('#edit').addClass(localStorage.getItem('class'));
});
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4X2FQ/9/)